# Gif not sending in facebook messenger Bot

Tags: facebook-messenger

Hi I am trying to send a gif in FB messenger. My code is as below

```
        function sendGif(sender) {
            let messageData = {
                "attachment": {
                    "type": "image",
                    "payload": {
                        "url": "http://giphy.com/gifs/tom-cruise-risky-business-movie-3jzoNumaV4o80",
                    }
                }
            }
            request({
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
                qs: {access_token:token},
                method: 'POST',
                json: {
                    recipient: {id:sender},
                    message: messageData,
                }
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error sending messages: ', error)
                } else if (response.body.error) {
                    console.log('Error: ', response.body.error)
                }
            })
        }
```

However, Im getting this error which is telling me that the file I am trying to attach is now allowed and to have a different format

```
2017-01-25T13:27:53.586498+00:00 app[web.1]: Error:  { message: '(#546) The type of file you\'re trying to attach isn\'t allowed. Please try again with a different format.',
2017-01-25T13:27:53.586508+00:00 app[web.1]:   type: 'OAuthException',
2017-01-25T13:27:53.586509+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 546,
2017-01-25T13:27:53.586510+00:00 app[web.1]:   error_subcode: 1545026,
2017-01-25T13:27:53.586511+00:00 app[web.1]:   fbtrace_id: 'BN+U/mDnnMi' }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: change your payload url to: `https://media.giphy.com/media/3jzoNumaV4o80/giphy.gif`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to send a `.html` file, not a gif.

The URL for gif is:

https://media.giphy.com/media/3jzoNumaV4o80/giphy.gif